Are Q# and the Microsoft Quantum Development Kit available for Visual Studio 2022?
A couple of years ago, the Microsoft Quantum Development Kit was introduced for Visual Studio 2022.  However, the published link now returns a Page Not Found message, and searching through the Visual Studio Marketplace does not bring up any relevant tools.
Doing a Google search for the QDK returns results only for the VS Code extension/tools.
Has Microsoft discontinued QDK and Q# support for the full version of Visual Studio?  Is VS Code the only option now?

According to these Q# Blog posts

Introducing the Azure Quantum Development Kit Preview (September 19th, 2023), and
Announcing v1.0 of the Azure Quantum Development Kit (January 12th, 2024),

the new, "Modern" QDK has been completely rewritten in Rust and all .NET and related dependencies have been dropped.
Also on Jan 12, 2024, Development on the now "Classic" QDK has been stopped.
As the "Classic" QDK contains the Visual Studio extension, I think it is safe to say that Microsoft discontinued QDK and Q# support for the full version of Visual Studio, and VS Code is the only option now.

Thank you @ax.  This answers my question
